# How do you check for bots with client side form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am asked to use only client side validation for a company's contact form because it is integrated with Eloqua but the contact form is attracting spammers. I want to know how I can check for bots. Is this possible?

Comment: You would only be able to check for bots that don't skip the client-side if you don't include some form of server-side validation.

Comment: Yes, it technically _is_, but it's a really nebulous concept. Tell me - how long is a piece of string? Also _never, ever rely on only client side validation_. If the requirements come from above, try to push back.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not a good practice, because it's so easy to hack.
client side code can be read, so hacked.
you can create your own recaptcha to verify in js (letters recognition, images,.. etc), and you will end up with a security system that a 10 years old can hack.

Comment: I am using Eloqua which collects the data from the form and Eloqua does not allow any server-side code. This means I cannot use PHP for server-side validation.